# Как преобразовать файл .py в .exe без PyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, c, exe, преобразование

Нужно файл в `python` собрать в `.exe` **БЕЗ использования `pytinstaller`**. Проблема в том, что при преобразовании через `pyinstaller`, все системы на него реагируют, **как на вирус**.

Comment: А что делает ваша программа? Если скачивает что-то с интернета и пишет в файлы, то антивирусы будут озабочены в любом случае.

Comment: самый надежный способ - переписать на любом компилируемом языке. на c/c++ может быть сложно (но не невозможно), на golang может быть достаточно просто.

Comment: Если Вы не хотите использовать *pytinstaller* то ведь можно сделать руками то, что он делает. А делает он вот что: "PyInstaller читает написанный вами скрипт Python. Он анализирует ваш код, чтобы обнаружить все остальные модули и библиотеки, которые необходимы вашему скрипту для выполнения. Затем он собирает копии всех этих файлов, включая активный интерпретатор Python! - и помещает их вместе со сценарием в одну папку или, при желании, в один исполняемый файл". Естественно, что подобная активность вызывает большие подозрения у антивирусов :-)

Comment: Так мне и надо избавиться от подозрений антивируса. Через cython перевел код питона в С, но через команду cl скрипт.py пишет, что необнаружен файл или папка Python.h

Comment: ну так найдите этот файл у себя в инсталляции  и делайте так   `cl /LD /I C:\python\include hello.c C:\python\libs\python36.lib`   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197984/visual-studio-cl-exe-cannot-find-python-h

Comment: Чтобы избавиться от подозрений антивирусов программу следует снабдить цифровой подписью и разослать вендорам антивирусов для анализа и занесения в белый список.

Comment: @KoVadim Не рабоатет скрипт огромное количество ошибок

Answer (score 0):

Не пробовали использовать `auto-py-to-exe`?

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

Для использования в консоли необходимо прописать:

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

Comment: Он использует pyinstaller. А значит, антивирусы буду считать его вирусом

Comment: `cx_Freeze` не пробовали?

Comment: нет,  а я там точно с помощью него найду ответ? Сами пробовали?

Comment: Сам пользуюсь только auto-py-to-exe. Но cx_Freeze не использует pyinstaller, поэтому может вам подойти. Правда порядок действий для компиляции немного заморочнее.

Comment: cx_Freeze тоже срабатывал когда-то.

Answer (score 0):

Для программы на `cython` нужна будет папка с питоном.

Но если папку все равно таскать, то возьми файл pip.exe, скопируй, переименуй. Открой через 7zipFM и замени содержимое `__main__.py` своим файлом.

Это можно сделать без хака если оформить вашу программу модулем для setuptools.

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='some-name',
      ...
      entry_points = {
              'console_scripts': [
                  'command-name = package.module:main_func_name',                  
              ],              
          },
)
```